# How do I loop through this number array to find if a number is <25 or >= 25?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Apologies in advance if this is too simple. It should say "Small number" nine times and "Big Number!" two times. Instead it hangs on the console.log. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
let numArray = [4, 2, 5, 10, 5, 3, 7, 22, 3, 70, 37];
    for (let i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++);
      let message = (numArray[i] > 25)? "Big Number!":
                    (numArray[i] <= 25)? "Small number"
                   console.log(message)
```

Comment: When asking a code related question, it is always necessary to add a tag for the language you're using. It helps get the question in front of the people most likely to be able to answer it. Please [edit] your post to add that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is **javascript** (or typescript perhaps) I see a few problems here.
First of the semicolon at the end of the *for* statement is ending the loop altogether without being executed as a code block you should remove it if you want to iterate through the array *numArray*

```js
for (let i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++)
```

Second, after you remove the semicolon at the end of that line if you intended to execute both the ternary operation (it didn't work for me on javascript if this is another language, it would be great if you can update your question and clarify that) and output to the console, you should enclose both lines in brackets, like so:

```js
{
    let message = (numArray[i] > 25) ? "Big Number!" : "Small number";
    console.log(message)
}
```

And of course, you are comparing the whole array not just an element, so you need to get an item using the index

```js
   numArray[i] > 25 ...
```

With those corrections, I can get the output that you are expecting (Small number nine times and Big number two times)

---

for the sake of clarity I've added (What i see) as the fixed code (in **javascript**/**typescript**) right below:

```js
let numArray = [4, 2, 5, 10, 5, 3, 7, 22, 3, 70, 37];
for (let i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
  let message = (numArray[i] > 25) ? "Big Number!" : "Small number";
  console.log(message)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's a great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code refers only to numArray as a whole, never to the i'th entry in numArray. You probably want to compare to `numArray[i]` or similar, rather than just numArray.

(also, may want to tag what language you're programming in, in case there are language-specific issues, but I'm pretty sure that issue will be a bug in any language)

Comment: Thanks for answering,  I'm sure it's obvious I'm new at this.

Comment: I added the [i], still the same issue. Thank you though, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Yeah, I don't program JS so I missed the other syntax issues posted in other answers. (This is one reason to tag with the language...)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrap your logic inside the for loop you actually forgot the { }  and no need to specify the second condition just put else.

```js
const numArray = [4, 2, 5, 10, 5, 3, 7, 22, 3, 70, 37];
for (let i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
  let message = numArray[i] > 25 ? "Big Number!" : "Small number"
  console.log(message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is not wrapped in curly braces. This is what it should look like:

```js
let numArray = [4, 2, 5, 10, 5, 3, 7, 22, 3, 70, 37];

for (let i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
  let message = (numArray[i] > 25) ? "Big Number!" : "Small number";
  console.log(message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues:

- Your for loop is not wrapped in curly brackets
- You mentioned being new at this, and I think avoiding the ternary operator would help make this more readable.

```js
let numArray = [4, 2, 5, 10, 5, 3, 7, 22, 3, 70, 37];
for (let i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
  if (numArray[i] > 25) {
      message = "Big Number!"
  } else {
      message = "Small number"
  }
  console.log(message)
}
```

If you really want to stick with the current structure, try this:

```js
let numArray = [4, 2, 5, 10, 5, 3, 7, 22, 3, 70, 37];
for (let i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++){
  (numArray[i] > 25)? message = "Big Number!" : message = "Small number"
  console.log(message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things to consider there, linked below to a nice book called [Eloquent Javascript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/index.html).

1. [Semicolons](https://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html#h_5fUOQZwwHx) ( ; )
2. [Ternary Operators](https://eloquentjavascript.net/01_values.html#c_G7eVm8ilWm) ( ? : ) i.e. condensed if...else
3. [For Loops](https://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html#h_oupMC+5FKN) ( for ( condition ) { operation } )

In short, I'd say (for now) to:

1. End your lines with a semicolon,
2. Before using a ternary (if...else), get a regular (if...else) scenario working and convert it to ternary,
3. Put all the bits you want to happen in a for loop, between curly braces {}.

Hopefully the above recommendations help to break things down a bit so you can solve several little chunks, rather than everything at once.